# Are there any restrictions to manually attaching events in jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events, tablefilter

I use picnet tablefilter in my application.

http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm

Tablefilter generates an input for each column. After entering some characters in an input, the filtering is triggered.

Wanting to make the header fixed I made a copy of that header and placed it so it floats right over the header used by tablefilter with `position: fixed`.

I built the same inputs with id = "my_filtertable_filter_3" instead of id = "filtertable_filter_3" like this:

```
$( '#fixed_table thead' ).append( '<tr class="filters">' + $( '#container thead .filters' ).html() + '</tr>' );

$( '#fixed_table thead .filters input' ).each( function( index )
{
    $( this ).attr( 'id', 'my_' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
});
```

So now I have a header that looks exactly like the header of picnet tablefilter in the demo, that flows over the original header giving the impression, that the header is fixed.

An illustration (without the picnet situation obviously) of the problem is posted here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2K7/21/

**What I want to achieve:**

When the user enters a string to the input with id = "my_filtertable_filter_3", this function will enter the same value to the input generated by picnet tablefilter. I also trigger the keyup event, that ( after reading picnets code for a few hours ) seems to be triggering the filter.

```
    $( '#fixed_table thead .filters input' ).keyup( function() 
    {
        var input_id  = $( this ).attr( 'id' ).substr( 3 );
        var input_val = $( this ).val() ;
        $( '#filtertable #hidden_thead .filters' ).find( 'input#filtertable_filter_3.filter' ).val( input_val );
        $( '#filtertable #hidden_thead .filters' ).find( 'input#filtertable_filter_3.filter' ).trigger('keyup');
    } );
```

While trying to catch this event like this, it seems to be working:

```
$( '#filtertable_filter_3' ).keyup( function()
{
    alert( 'event caught' );
});
```

**My question:**

Is this an absolutely wrong approach to the problem, or am I just not firing the right event?

**Problem:**

As said in the comment below: the alert is fired, but the filter is not filtering ( the input value is filled. )

Comment: It seems like the right approach to the situation to me. You say "it seems to be working" but also "am I just not firing the right event", so is your issue that it fires the alert but does not stop the original function?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, cant believe it but forgot to write the problem :) The alert is fired, but the filter is not triggered.

Comment: No. The DOM looks like this. `$('body #fixed_table thead .filters input#my_fitertable_filter_3')` for the 'visible' header. For the actual input where the user would enter the string she/he wants to filter the DOM looks like this: `$('body #container #filtertable #hidden_table .filters input#fitertable_filter_3')`

Comment: no, there was a ctrl+v error in my previous comment. They share an id only for a short while as illustrated in the first block of code in my question (before the **'my_'** prefix is added).

Comment: the fixed table is separated from the actual one, if this might be any help.

Comment: The keyup function should be firing correctly based on what you have said. [I recreated it here](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2K7/). Double check that you have spelled everything correctly (in the comments you had `my_fitertable_filter_3` as opposed to `my_filtertable_filter_3`). Also, is `#hidden_thead` in the keyup function suppose to be `#hidden_table`? I don't see `#hidden_thead` anywhere else in the code you provided

Comment: Since you're already using ID's, you can just use a selector with only that ID [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2K7/13/). Your problem seems to be lying in the `$( '#filtertable #hidden_thead .filters' ).find(...` lines, so only using `input#idhere` removes that problem

Comment: Hey, I've updated your fiddle to illustrate exactly how the situation looks after the first block of code fires => http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2K7/21/

Comment: This works, but the filter is not triggered. I need to know, if by firing the object.trigger('keyup') is a good solution when I want to simulate, that a user clicked and entered a string into the input. If so, than I know I have to dig some more in the picnet's tablefilter and find out what exactly is being targeted when the user enters string into the filter.

Comment: if not, maybe someone who understands the subject deeply could explain how triggering events work and why this approach is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Did not find out what event I should trigger, but appended the original inputs to the fixed head and it seems to be working. So my solution was a huge overkill (at least I learned tons about events and event handlers).

If there is anybody who uses picnet tablefilter and wants to make a fixed table head, this, with the css&html from my jsfiddle will suffice.

```
$( '#okno #filtertable thead .filters' ).appendTo( '#fixed_table thead' );
```